# In Corda, how can two nodes prove to each other that they both know a piece of information?

Tags: corda

I want to write a Corda flow where two parties only proceed with a transaction if they can both prove they share a common piece of information. The outline of the flow would be as follows:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class ChallengeResponseFlow(val otherParty: Party, val proofOfKnowledge: Int) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)
        otherPartySession.send(proofOfKnowledge)
        val theirProofOfKnowledge = otherPartySession.receive<Int>().unwrap { theirProofOfKnowledge -> theirProofOfKnowledge }
        verifySecretValue(theirProofOfKnowledge)

        TODO("Challenge-response passed. Continue with flow.")
    }

    private fun verifyTheirProofOfKnowledge(theirProofOfKnowledge: Int) {
        TODO("Write verification logic.")
    }
}
```

Two questions:

- What could the proof-of-knowledge be here to prove that I know the same secret as my counterparty?
- How can I check that my counterparty knows the same secret based on the proof-of-knowledge they send me?

It's important that during this challenge-response protocol, the secret is never revealed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your requirements there are various strategies:

1. Assuming the secret has enough entropy (i.e., at least 128 bits), both parties can pick a random `nonce` and send `SHA3-256(secret, nonce)` or `SHA2-256d` (double hash) or even better `HMAC` along with their `nonce` to the other party.

*NoteA:* As you've noticed, I omitted simple SHA256 as it's susceptible to [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

*NoteB:* sending half of the hash, as already mentioned by @Kid101, will still work, but it reduces security level, so the nonce approach is considered more secure and elegant.

*NoteC:* The nonce approach provides the extra (probably desired) unlinkability property, according to which a malicious attacker cannot tell if the same `secret` is reused in two different transactions/flows. What is needed is always generating a new random nonce.

2. There are cases however, where the secret does not have enough entropy or it's not random at all (i.e., a counter or a predictable `String` such as a weak password or userID). Then, one (man-in-the-middle) can simply brute-force the simple hash or MAC approach (even when a nonce is applied) to easily extract the "weak" secret. Solutions to this problem are more complex, requiring some kind of encryption (i.e., send the hashed messages via a secure channel or by using a [password authenticated key agreement protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement)).

*NoteD:* Corda nodes are connected via TLS anyway, but if you need to secure data at rest (i.e., checkpoints) one should use an extra layer of encryption.

3. If one wants to provide security against replay attacks, a challenge-response protocol is required. By replay attack we mean that the same nonce is reused on purpose (i.e., a previous authentication-token was somehow compromised and reused in a future authentication attempt). One trick for the 1st case (secret with enough entropy) is to receive a challenging-nonce from the counter-party and use this nonce for the authentication token `SHA3-256(secret, nonce)`. So, each client uses the nonce received by other party.
4. Extending the above challenge-response solution, it is sometimes advisable to use both nonces, e.g,

**Party A sends `SHA3-256(secret, noncefromPartyA, noncefromPartyB)`**

and

**Party B sends `SHA3-256(secret, noncefromPartyB, noncefromPartyA)`**

This is to provide extra guarantees that the aggregated nonce is controlled by both parties and if just one of them is malicious or its PRNG is flawed you can still produce unique nonces.

*NoteE*: We should ensure that **`noncefromPartyA != noncefromPartyB`**, because the one who replies second could just reuse (forward) the same authentication token with the first party (again a type of replay attack).

*NoteF*: Along the same lines, we highlight that the order of nonces in the above hashes should be different to again protect against internal replay attacks, even when we use different nonces per user!

Comment: kudos to the nonce !

Answer (score 0):

I can hash my secret with SHA256 send first 128bits to the other side and let other side check if his secrets SHA256 hash matches with first 128 bits of his.  then he can send his second half to the first party to verify if it matches with his.

Comment: I think this would not prevent brute-forcing

Comment: yeah @RomanPlášil. I just thought of the question as a puzzle to solve from the top of my head rather than considering all aspects of security. Chalkias has done a great job providing the answer considering every key aspect.